# Why doesn't docker accept non-local MAC addresses?

Tags: docker

If I run `docker run --mac-address=00:16:3E:08:00:50 ubuntu ifconfig` I get the error

> setup networking set eth0 mac Incorrect Local MAC Address specified: 00:16:3e:08:00:50FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 37569a756349235c2f669989d47bf2495f5adc2ecbe1768038ae4ca050ceeaae: setup networking set eth0 mac Incorrect Local MAC Address specified: 00:16:3e:08:00:50

From https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/vendor/src/github.com/docker/libcontainer/netlink/netlink_linux.go#L528 I see that docker doesn't accept non-local MAC addresses. Why is that not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

It is rejecting addresses which are not locally *administered*. Which seems fair, considering how much the IEEE charges for an [OUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizationally_Unique_Identifier).

Comment: So there is no technical reason to behave this way, right? There are good reasons to assign an OUI to a docker container, like there are good reasons to assign an OUI to a virtual machine, which is possibile. In my case for example I have a third party software that is bound to a MAC address. I used to run it on a real machine (which I still own), then I moved it to a virtual machine and now I would like to move it into a container. Should I give up?

Comment: I suggest raising an issue on the Docker GitHub. Don't see how there can be any technical reason for the exclusion.